# No ntbtlog.txt after enabling Boot Logging

Tags: windows-10, boot, logging

My windows 10 box needs ages for booting, so I've tried to enable boot logging to find out what is taking this time. I've enabled it by using msconfig and another time by calling

```
bcdedit /set {current} bootlog Yes
```

The corresponding value shows as yes, when checking:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit
[...]
Windows-Startladeprogramm
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}
[...]
bootlog                 Yes
```

But: After rebooting, no ntbtlog.txt shows up in %windir% and a `find -name ntbtlog.txt` (using Cygwin) doesn't come up with another location for a file of this name.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or if there is another/better way to get a log of the booting sequence including timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The log file is found in `C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt`.
(I don't advise using Cygwin for finding and viewing Windows files.)

For more information see the article
[How to Enable and Find Your Windows Boot Log](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-boot-log-guide/).

Comment: I've used msconfig, I've used bcdedit, I've checked %windir%, so can you point me to the part in the article you've linked that I haven't described as already done in my question?

Comment: Yes, section "Where Is the Windows Boot Log Saved". You have done everything correctly, you just have a spelling mistake in the file-name...

Comment: I've fixed my quesion by correcting the name of the log. The problem remains the same. That particular file can't be found in the directory it's supposed to be. There are no files that start with `nt`at all, be it a log-file or otherwise.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin or Windows Explorer (or CMD `dir`) ?

Comment: I've looked into %windir" using Windows Explorer, the dir-command in cmd.exe and used `find -name ntbtlog.txt` on /cygdrive/c to check for other locations than %windir% with that file.

Comment: I'm on Windows 11, but in Windows 10 I think there is also a setting for boot logging in *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options*. If you still can't find the file, check if it's not in the Event Viewer, Windows Logs section. If all fails, I suggest to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).